# How to set the background color of a word?

Tags: c#, forms, background-color, picturebox

I have a pictureBox in a Form. In the middle of that pictureBox, I've placed the name of a chosen photo.
Now, I want to color the background of that chosen name.

How can I do that?

Comment: Some code would help people. How have you placed the name? With a label? Have you tried setting the background of the label? If you are using a different technique the code would really help!

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but a PictureBox's content is an image. If you want to simply display text, use a Label. If you want it to have a specific background color, set its BackColor property to the color that you want.

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var label = new Label {BackColor = Color.White};
    Controls.Add(label);
}
```

EDIT:

I allowed myself to re-use part of Sampath's example above to adapt it to the user's comment.

```
void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var font = new Font("Arial", 14))
    {
        const string pictureName = "Picture.jpg";
        var textPosition = new Point(10, 10);
        //Drawing logic begins here.
        var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(pictureName, font);
        var rect = new RectangleF(textPosition.X, textPosition.Y, size.Width, size.Height);
        //Filling a rectangle before drawing the string.
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(pictureName, font, Brushes.Green, textPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,

i meant that i have the name of a photo. this photo is shown in the picturebox. and i would like to change the backgrond of the name (not the background of the photo)...  i've already used "e.Graphics.DrawString" to place the word in the center of the pictureBox. what can i do?

Comment: Sampath, Eve, Thank you very much! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sample.

Just add a **picture box** to your form, and **add an event handler for the Paint event:**

You want to use the **Paint event** in the PictureBox. You get the **graphics reference** from **e.Graphics**, and then use the **DrawString()** that you have in your sample.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello .NET Guide!", myFont, Brushes.Green, new Point(2, 2));
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to you.

Comment: This draws the text with a certain color (i. e. the **foreground** color).  The OP asked how to change the **background** color.  The only way I can think of to do that is to first draw a rectangle of the desired background color and then draw the text as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be as simple as changing the background color property for the control, which you change in the properties window.